# mean in R: argument is not numeric

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace the values of a column with NA with the mean of the column.

I already tried the following solutions:

```
titanic3$age[which(is.na(titanic3$age))] <- mean(titanic3$age, use = 
"complete.obs") 
titanic3$age[which(is.na(titanic3$age))] <- mean(titanic3[,age], use = 
"complete.obs")
titanic3$age[which(is.na(titanic3$age))] <- mean(titanic3[[age]], use = 
"complete.obs")
```

But it didn´t work. Any ideas?

Comment: use `mean(titanic3$age, na.rm = TRUE)`? Also second and third would need to be `titanic3[, "age"]` and `titanic3[["age"]]`

Comment: can the argument "use" be passed at all to the function mean?

Answer (score 2):

We can do this easily with `na.aggregate`

```
library(zoo)
titanic3$age <- na.aggregate(titanic3$age)
```

By default, the `FUN` would be `mean` to replace the `NA` values with the `mean` of that column

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
titanic3$age[is.na(titanic3$age)] <- mean(titanic3$age, na.rm = T)
```